# SQL query optimization and debugging

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, optimization

the question is about the best practice.

**How to perform a reliable SQL query test?**

That is the question is about optimization of DB structure and SQL query itself not the system and DB performance, buffers, caches.

When you have a complicated query with a lot of joins etc, one day you need to understand how to optimize it and you come to `EXPLAIN` command ([mysql::explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), [postresql::explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html)) to study the execution plan.

After tuning the DB structure you execute the query to see any performance changes but here you're on the pan of multiple level of optimization/buffering/caching. How to avoid this? I need the *pure* time for the query execution and be sure it is not affected.

If you know different practise for different servers please specify explicitly: mysql, postgresql, mssql etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For Microsoft SQL Server you can use `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` (to drop compiled query plans) and `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` (to purge the data cache) to ensure that you are starting from a completely uncached state.  Then you can profile both uncached and cached performance, and determine your performance accurately in both cases.

Even so, a lot of the time you'll get different results at different times depending on how complex your query is and what else is happening on the server.  It's usually wise to test performance multiple times in different operating scenarios to be sure you understand what the full performance profile of the query is.

I'm sure many of these general principles apply to other database platforms as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the PostgreSQL world you need to flush the database cache as well as the OS cache as PostgreSQL leverages the OS caching system.

See this link for some discussions.

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2010-08/msg00295.php

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need *pure* execution time? It depends on so many factors and almost meaningless on live server. I would recommend to collect some statistic from live server and analyze queries execution time using [pgfouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/) tool (it's for postgresql) and make decisions based on it. You will see exactly what do you need to tune and how effective was your changes on a report.

Comment: OK, thank you for the link. Yes you're right, but ones you know which query to optimize you encounter the subsequent problem. For mysql there is also good log analyser: http://myprofi.sourceforge.net/